# Web Mapping application. Use of Geoserver: YES or NOT?

Tags: leaflet, geoserver

What are the benefits and / or needs to use Geoserver in the development of a web mapping application?

In other words, is it required to use a server such as "Geoserver" for the optimal development of a web mapping application?

I have created a web mapping application with Leaflet to publish geological and geophysical data. All data are already conditioned to be displayed in an Internet browser (data formats and styles are ready). My data and assets are stored in folders in the Apache directory of my PC. The application works and runs "perfectly".

Why should I implement Geoserver (or MapServer)?

I will really appreciate suggestions/opinions.

Answer (score 4):

Of course, there is no reason that you have to implement GeoServer. However, there are variety of reasons why others do. Here are just a few.

1. GeoServer would allow you to manage datasets that are far larger than those that can be managed within a browser.
2. GeoServer can serve data through a variety of services, including WMS, WFS, WCS, WPS, etc.
3. GeoServer / GeoWebCache continue to perform well in environments with lots of geospatial data and lots of users.
4. If you thought that you might want to consume a variety geospatial data sources, then GeoServer is useful. It can consume all sorts of other geospatial data sources, including ESRI, PostGIS, OGC, etc. In fact, via GeoWebCache, it can even cache that data within your local network and reduce traffic to the external servers. GeoServer can even unify data from these disparate sources onto single layers (group).
5. GeoServer has lots of great styling options. You can use SLD, CSS, and Mapbox styles. Styles can be property and scale-sensitive.
6. GeoServer can transform data from a source on the fly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: see also https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15616/why-do-we-need-mapserver-geoserver-to-present-data-from-spatial-database-to-web/15619#15619

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It was exactly what I needed